# How to interpret java ssl debug output

Tags: java, ssl

Hello my https request is returning this exception javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

And this is my debug output

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1515663662 bytes = { 160, 16, 29, 166, 43, 3, 9, 234, 105, 145, 41, 140, 254, 201, 135, 187, 135, 225, 4, 5, 118, 153, 239, 207, 64, 149, 190, 195 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
myExecutor-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163


myExecutor-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
myExecutor-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
myExecutor-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
myExecutor-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
myExecutor-1, called closeSocket()
myExecutor-1, IOException in getSession():  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
myExecutor-1, called close()
myExecutor-1, called closeInternal(true)
myExecutor-1, called close()
myExecutor-1, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
```

I also installed the Java Cryptography Extension and not working yet

Comment: The message is clear: it failed because the peer is not authenticated.

Comment: I would like to know if the error is coming from server ssl config, maybe tlsv1.2. I want to know what is the origin of SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Answer (score 1):

How to interpret:

> Is initial handshake: true ->Its the first contact,best place to show warnings to the user if its fishy
>
> No cached client session -> we have no session
>
> %% No cached client session -> the socket is open
>
> WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163 -> Handshake is sending
>
> myExecutor-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset -> the socket is closed
>
> **handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** -> start the client's exception-handling. By client I mean the browser, not the server. The Putty not the SSHD.
>
> **myExecutor-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message** the socket is closed but the exception-handling does not know the socket is closed, to try to send a alert to the server is hopeless since the socket is closed. Yes, in the case of closed socket the client should not try to send a alert to the server, this might be a bug but with no impact.
>
> **myExecutor-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2** now he tries to send the alert to the sender but this *must* produce a following-exception because the socket is closed.
>
> **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated** > here we go

Unfortunately the server gives no information why he quits the connection. There can be multiple options:

1. The cable to the server has been cut by a knife.
2. The software-server died.
3. The hardware-server died.
4. The server does not use the TLS protocol but a different protocol that is incompatible.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer, What I cannot see is the ServerHello maybe is using a different tls version?

Comment: @david.dev If so the server response with 70 (protocol_version) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246 and a SSLException `Received fatal alert: protocol_version` is thrown.

Comment: In browsers like firefox and chrome work fine, but for example in firefox if I disable the TLSv1.2 the browser cannot download the url,  so I suspect that the server only accepts TLSv1.2 connections

Comment: @david.dev Do you know what SSL server and what version is the server?

Comment: No, I haven't that info

Comment: I'm using Apache httpclient 4.1, java 1.7.0_80 and what I want is enable TLSv1.2 in my client application

Comment: @david.dev maybe you are connecting to the wrong url?